# PostgreSQL Alternate Database Location

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and have a separate partition for my root directory. The partition wasn't set up with large databases in mind, so I would like to put my 2+GB PostgreSQL database on the /home partition.

The first piece of advice I ran into was the `initlocation` command, but this is apparently for older versions of PostgreSQL.

Then I ran into the `initdb` command, but this doesn't appear to be available on Ubuntu 10.10... for some reason.

How should I do this really?

Comment: You may ask this kind of questions on http://DBA.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command [`initdb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/initdb.1.html) should be located at path `/usr/lib/postgresql/{version}/bin/initdb` (propably not included in your `PATH`), however you could use [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) wrapper, especially with `-D` option:

> This  option  specifies the directory where the database cluster
>   should be stored. This  is  the  only  information  required  by
>   **initdb**,  but  you  can  avoid  writing  it by setting the **PGDATA**
>   environment variable, which can be convenient since the database
>   server  (**postgres**)  can find the database directory later by the same
>   variable.

Comment: Somehow, by messing up my old install, I managed to use `pg_createcluster` to set up the default database cluster to just the place where I wanted it... a command which PostGre suggested itself when it failed to set things up correctly. So you certainly got this one right on.

Answer (score 0):

The files that describe the default cluster, called main, are located in the directory /etc/postgresql/8.4/main for 8.4 on my ubuntu 10.10 machine.  Just stop postgresql, copy your data dir over to the new dir, set perms (700 on the root dir, and owned by the postgres user) edit the line in postgresql.conf that points to your data dir and restart postgres.

Comment: alternately you can use the pg_createcluster command to create a new cluster and import your data into that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and PostgreSQL 8.4. Here's what I did to move my pgdata folder off the root partition, loosely based on [instructions from linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/change-postgresql-data-directory-649911/#post3187503).

1. `cd /mnt/workspace` to get to the folder I want to hold my new pgdata folder.
2. `ls -l ..` to make sure that the `workspace` folder is owned by root.
3. `grep data_directory /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf` to see where the current data directory is. In my case it was `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main`.
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 stop` to stop the service.
5. `sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main /mnt/workspace/pgdata` to move the data folder to its new location.
6. `ls -l` to make sure that the `pgdata` folder is still owned by the postgres user.
7. I edited the `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf` file to point the `data_directory` entry at its new location.
8. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 start` to start the service.
9. Try connecting to the database server to make sure it still works.
10. `df` to see how much free space I now have on the root partition. Woot!